# Scheduling Task in WP7 Mango

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am on an initial stage of creating a Birthday reminder application in WP7 Mango.. So in my app i can create a specific theme for each birthday reminders. ie a view with some kind of images, sounds and birthday notification etc. Assuming that my App is active on the background, how i can schedule this birthday notifications , and also how i can navigate to that reminder view to get notification. Any one please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So in my app i can create a specific theme for each birthday reminders. ie a view with some kind of images, sounds and birthday notification etc

You can't create Reminders with a custom layout.

> Assuming that my App is active on the background, how i can schedule this birthday notifications

By "background" do you mean "under the lock screen" ? Otherwise, there's no such thing as having it running in the background.

You can have a `ScheduledTask` , which runs every 30 minutes and checks, which then can create a toast, or update a Live Tile. But that's also it.

Comment: By using "ScheduledTask"  Is it possible to open a view of an applications. Like scheduling applications in windows.

Comment: No. You can only display a Toast, which when clicked, opens your application.

Answer (score -4):

Rakesh whatever you are asking can be done very easily in Android.  But I am sure It is possible in Windows phone also.

I think this might helps you [Scheduling tasks on Windows Phone 7](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/scheduling-tasks-windows-phone?mz=27249-windowsphone7)